# WebForm Data Binding to SQL Database

Tags: sql, webforms

I'm learning the basics of WebForms by following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/updating-deleting-and-creating-data

I've been able to insert the data from the website directly into a database. I'm facing now another issue. After the button of the form is pressed, I'd like to get the inserted data in my code so I can perform some calculations and then insert the data into the database.

Is it possible to achieve this with the method suggested in the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the `addStudentForm_InsertItem()` method as shown below.

```
public void addStudentForm_InsertItem()
{
    var item = new Student();

    TryUpdateModel(item);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

**//Do your modifications, calculations here, and set the updated properties on item.**

```
        using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
        {
            db.Students.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It seems to be the best solution!